# Troubleshoot my mobile background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

So, I have kind of edited a theme I downloaded. I didn't change much, just some color codes of backgrounds.

It was working for a while until I started trying to mess with making the navbar extend all the way left to right of the screen.

I was just trying to make the black extend but keep the logo positioning and menu items where they are at currently horizontally

**CSS**

```
/* CUSTOM CSS */

.site-logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
}
.site-header {
background: #000823;
.entry-thumbnail {
  border: none;
}

.entry-title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

body {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: roboto, line-height: 1.8;
  background: #e5f2ff;
}

.wp-caption {
  border: none;
}

.wp-caption {
  background-color: #000 !important;
  margin-bottom: 1.0em;
}

body {
  background-size: contain !important;
}
}
body {
color: #333;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 1.8;
background: #F5FAFC;
}
#primary {
background: #F5FAFC;
}
#widget-area-2 {
background: #F5FAFC;
.clearfix {
  clear: none !important;
}

.entry-thumbnail {
  border: none;
}

.wp-caption {
  border: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3twb4mr6/)

Comment: Where is the HTML section. The only thing you posted is the CSS file which has a lot of syntax errors in it. Mostly some extra and some missing brackets. Don't just post a wall of HTML text either, please show us only the relative bits. Thanks!

Comment: i have changed nothing in the HTML though, and i wouldn't know where to begin on HTML, i just started on css and wordpress 4 days ago. this is what ive accomplished so far, www.offtopicpolitics.com

Comment: You will need to explain the issue more. I don't understand what you are asking. Maybe you could give us a picture.

Comment: i included the link^

Answer (score 0):

The nav is inside a container wrapper div. The container is restricting the width of its contents. You need to pull it out, or you won't be able to reasonably get it full width. Right now your setup is:

```
<header>
    <div class="clearfix container">
        <!-- stuff -->
        <nav class="main-navigation" id="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <!-- nav content -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

What you will need is:

```
<header>
    <nav class="main-navigation" id="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <!-- nav content -->
    </nav>
    <div class="clearfix container">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </div>
</header>
```

When outside the container, the nav will easily expand to full width.